# Launching JNLP from CentoOS 7 Gnome Desktop with PATH

Tags: java, jnlp, centos7, gnome-3

I have a JNLP application that uses the local $PATH variable. It launches and behaves correctly from the web, command line, menu system, and Java control panel. When I launch it from the desktop shortcut on CentOS 7, the $PATH is simply

`/bin:/lib:/usr/bin:/usr/lib:/usr/share/bin:/usr/share/lib`

regardless of what else I put in the /etc/profile.d/, or ~/.bashrc, or anyplace else that I can find. It only seems to affect CentOS 7. CentOS 6.x, OS X, and Windows all behave normally when launching from their Desktop environments.

I am using Oracle's 32-bit Java 1.8.0_60 on the 64-bit CentOS 7 for specific application requirement reasons. I have uninstalled IcedTea, but still have OpenJDK 1.7 installed, though it is not used by the JNLP application and the alternatives have been configured to use Oracle's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution that I have found is:

1. Disable shortcut creation in the Java control panel > Advanced settings
2. Create a shell script that contains these two lines:

   > ```
   > source /etc/profile
   > javaws < location-of-jnlp >
   > ```
3. Create a .desktop file that calls the shell script

It's not an ideal solution, but it works for the short run.